# Show that the entries of the main diagonal of square matrix give the degrees of the vertices of the graph

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, matrix-equations, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph, and $A$ be its adjacency matrix. Prove
that the entries on the main diagonal of $A^2$
(matrix multiplication $A×A =A^2$) give the degrees of the vertices of $G$. Does this remain true if we drop the "simple" condition?

Please help me in constructing the proof. I don't know what to start. Thank you.

Comment: Three close-votes and one down-vote. All drive-bys: no explanation. Same on the OP's other questions. _What a warm and welcoming place SE is for new users_ /s Classic SE toxicity

Comment: @SamOT You made me stop my reviewing to leave a suggestion to anony-mous: Please add more detail like information or some research you have about the problem. Welcome here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think about what $(A^2)_{i,i}$, the $i$-th term on the diagonal is. We have
$$ \textstyle (A^2)_{i,i} = (A \times A)_{i,i} = \sum_j A_{i,j} A_{j,i}. $$
But $A_{i,j} = A_{j,i}$, assuming that the graph is undirected, and $A_{i,j} = 1(i \sim j)$, ie is $1$ if $i$ and $j$ are adjacent and $0$ otherwise. Thus $A_{i,j} A_{j,i} = A_{i,j}^2 = A_{i,j} = 1(i \sim j)$. So the sum is just the number of $j$ such that $i \sim j$, which is precisely the degree.

This works if vertices in your graph may have a single self-loop, provided you count that as $1$ (not $2$) for the degree. Indeed, the term in the sum when $j = i$ is just $A_{i,i}^2$, but you need this to be equal to $A_{i,i}$. Thus it needs to be $0$ or $1$.

It does not work more generally, however, as $A_{i,j}^2 \ne A_{i,j}$ if $A_{i,j} > 1$.

Incidentally, if you look at $A^T A$---which, in some sense, is actually a more natural sense of 'squaring' a matrix---then you immediately get
$$ \textstyle (A^T A)_{i,i} = \sum_j A_{i,j}^2 = \deg_\mathrm{out}(i), $$
even for an undirected graph, provided the graph is simple.

Comment: Oh. Thank you for giving me an idea.

Comment: @anony-mous You say "an idea". I did give a full proof, though. Is there some part you don't follow? :)

Comment: I'm trying to write my own proof to practice. I appreciate that you have given me an aid. Thank you.

Comment: Excellent that you're doing so! So many users just come here for a quick answer then move on without really thinking about it. Your method will benefit you in the long run :)

Comment: Thank you. I do have a question. Does the premise still hold if we only consider graph and not simple graph?

Comment: @anony-mous I do address this in my answer :) -- it depends on your definition of "simple". It holds if you allow the possibility of a single self-loop at the vertices. But it doesn't hold if you have multiple edges. This is due to $A_{i,j}^2 \ne A_{i,j}$ if $A_{i,j} > 1$, as I wrote

Comment: @anony-mous has this solved it for you? You should accept an answer to signal that your question is answered. Either accept mine or you can write your own (with appropriate acknowledgements) and accept that :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: @anony-mous Not a problem! Glad to help. You can also upvote since it helped. As well as definitely upvoting ones that helped you, it's nice to upvote answers that are good on other questions! I'm sorry that you've been subject to the SE classic drive-by down/close vote. Your questions could be a bit better, but people don't tend to say or explain how; they just vote. You should look to include more details regarding what you've done. Even if you're completely stuck at the start, say what stuff you know that is relevant, etc. Definitely say what you've tried. You'll get a much better reception